# Two UIToolBar appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitoolbar

We have UITableViewController in which we are giving table edit functionality like attached screenshot. And we want to show/hide bottom toolbar for bar button items.

[image]

for edit we are using below code.

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:false];
editButton.title = @"Cancel";
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

After this code we are getting toolbar like the given image (two toolbars). How to remove white toolbar?

Thanks

Edit:

We are getting this issue when we are doing pushViewController:

```
TransactionsListViewController *callTransactionsListViewController=[[TransactionsListViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:callTransactionsListViewController animated:YES];
```

In presentViewController we are not getting above issue:

```
TransactionsListViewController *callTransactionsListViewController=[[TransactionsListViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:callTransactionsListViewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In ViewDidLoad

```
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
```

TableView Edit on button tap:

```
-(IBAction)btEdit:(id)sender{
    if (self.tableView.editing)
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:false];
        editButton.title = @"Edit";
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:false];
        editButton.title = @"Cancel";
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The white toolbar is not actually a toolbar. I think that when you show the toolbar for some reason table view gets twice offset from the bottom. It may be system issue or code in your application. It would be helpful if you could specify view and view controller hierarchy on this screen and any custom layout you apply to table view.

Comment: @varun When do you start editing? On viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad or button tap?